# Are there any RPGs with an insane amount of stats?

Tags: game-recommendation, statistics

Are there any RPGs with a ridiculous amount of stats?  I'm not looking for an enjoyable play experience, just a game with many stats to see how crazy and complicated it is.

(The reason being I want to see how the mechanics were designed around the stats or vice versa.)

Comment: We require far more details here. What is "insane?" What is "sane?" (and for that matter, what is a stat?) What genre? What kind of game are you looking to design?

Comment: This may be a duplicate of [this question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/53176/4398); at the very least, you can probably glean bits from that question to help narrow down this one.

Comment: There are many, many games which require you to track large numbers of numbers, and they all deal with it in different ways and for different reasons. Some track numbers that only come up in obscure edge cases, while in others, all the numbers are used regularly. Some have resolution mechanics that require numbers to be added or otherwise combined in complex calculations, while others track very large quantities of stats precisely to reduce the amount of calculation required to resolve some situations while still maintaining playability. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: Ahem. let's avoid actually answering in comments, yes? Perhaps migrate these to a chat room where we can revel in their awful?

Comment: Because these comments are just vibrating full of energy wanting to revel in the glory and horror of these kinds of systems, let's take it to chat. [***To the chatmobile!***](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21700/chat-about-all-the-stats)